# "/recaptcha/api2/logo_48.png" blocked by Google

Tags: robots.txt

I have a contact form on my site, it all works fine. I also using Google Captcha for that form.

When I go to my G search console to make sure all is fine, I see I get one error stating:

> Googlebot couldn't get all resources for this page. Here's a list:
>
> ```
> https://www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/api2/logo_48.png  << Blocked
> ```

I have gone to my robots.txt file and added the following but that didnt help

```
Allow: https://www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/api2/logo_48.png
Allow: /recaptcha/api2/logo_48.png
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your own robots.txt is only for URLs from your host.

The message is about a URL from a different host (`www.gstatic.com`). This host would have to edit [its robots.txt file](https://www.gstatic.com/robots.txt) to allow crawling of `/recaptcha/api2/logo_48.png`. It’s currently disallowed.

In other words: You can’t control the crawling of files that are hosted by someone else.

Comment: So... what can be done then in such case to make the error dissapear from Google Search Console? It looks weird that Google reCaptcha blocks a resource and then Google Search Console itself tells you it could not access that image...

Comment: @andcl: I would say you don’t need to do anything -- it informs you of the blocked resource, but that doesn’t mean that is *has* to be unblocked. -- I’m not familiar with reCaptcha, but maybe it is possible to change the widget and host the logo yourself (`/recaptcha/api2/logo_48.png`)?